# Term for "opposite" items that are actually similar

Tags: expressions, synonyms

Is there a term (like "pseudo-synonym") for things that are colloquially considered opposites when in fact they are part of the same set on a higher level?

For example, "cats and dogs" are "opposites" but in reality are both quadrupedal animals. Or "apples and oranges" which are both actually fruit from trees.

Comment: I don't know about a single term, but I've heard the saying "we're/they're not as different as you'd/they'd like to believe".

Answer (score 2):

First, let me diagnose the error. To say that 'cats' is the opposite of 'dogs' is to confuse *antonymy* with *collocation*. Likewise for 'apples' and 'oranges.' Both children and adults commonly make this error.

I know of no conventional word for these dubious antonyms (although [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_(semantics)) suggests there *are* terms for different types of antonyms). ***Pseudoantonym*** and ***false antonym*** sprang to mind. Unfortunately, these words are already in use for a different concept (see [here](http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/False%20Antonyms.html)).

You might use ***folk antonym***, where ***folk*** means:

> Relating to or originating from the beliefs and opinions of ordinary people ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/folk))

This is the same way 'folk' is used in the expression ***folk etymology***:

> A popular but mistaken account of the origin of a word or phrase ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/folk-etymology?q=folk%20etymology)).

Parodying this defintion, we might define ***folk antonym*** as:

> A popular but mistaken antonym of a word or phrase.